# Q-multinomial coefficient combinatorial meaning

Tags: multinomial-coefficients, q-analogs

Could anyone please explain to me a combinatorial meaning for the expression ${n \choose{k_1,k_2,...,k_r}} _q$,where $_q$ means a q-multinomial coefficient. I understand what a normal multinomial coefficient means, but when I consider the q-analog I am quite confused on what interpretation to give to this expression.

Comment: It's a good idea most often to tell where you saw a notation being used.  Should Readers assume the meaning of multinomial coefficients is already known to you?

Comment: You're right, sorry I added some more detail to the question.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.math.hmc.edu/seniorthesis/archives/2007/jazose/jazose-2007-thesis.pdf) and [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-MultinomialCoefficient.html). Google is your friend! :) Check [this](http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/~guoniu/papers/p56lectnotes2.pdf) too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps someone more familiar with the subject will be able to provide more, but one combinatorial interpretation can be found in **Theorem** $\mathbf{5.1}$ of [this PDF](http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/~guoniu/papers/p56lectnotes2.pdf). If $W$ is the set of all rearrangements of the word $1^{k_1}2^{k_2}\ldots r^{k_r}$, where $k_1+\ldots+k_r=n$, then

$$\binom{n}{k_1,\ldots,k_r}_q=\sum_{w\in W}q^{\operatorname{inv}w}\;,$$

where $\operatorname{inv}w$ is the number of inversions of $w$. The authors note that some of the common combinatorial interpretations of the $q$-binomial coefficient don’t extend easily to the $q$-multinomial.

Answer (score 1):

The multinomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k_1,\dotsc,k_r}_q$ counts the number of flags
$$
0=V_0\subset \dotsb \subset V_r=\mathbf F_q^n
$$
of linear subspaces such that $\dim V_i/V_{i-1} = k_i$ for $i=1,\dotsc,r$.
See, for example, Section 5 of  [Counting subspaces of a finite vector space](https://Counting%20subspaces%20of%20a%20finite%20vector%20space).