# Area under a lattice path, from q-binomial to q-multinomial

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, q-analogs

The $q$-binomial ${n+k \choose k}_q$ is a polynomial in $q$. The coefficient of each power $t \leq nk$ of $q$ gives the number of lattice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,k)$ which enclose an area $t$ beneath.

The $q$-multinomial ${n_1+n_2+\dots+n_N \choose n_1,n_2,\dots,n_N}_q$ is also polynomial in $q$. When $q=1$, as expected, you get the number of lattice paths from the origin of the hypercuboid of dimension $n_1 \times \dots \times n_N$ to the vector  $(n_1,\dots,n_N)$. For example:
$${8 \choose 3,3,2}_1=560$$
But! Notice this...
$${8 \choose 3,3,2}_q = 1 + 2 q + 5 q^2 + 9 q^3 + 15 q^4 + 22 q^5 + 31 q^6 + 39 q^7 + 
 47 q^8 + 53 q^9 + 56 q^{10} + 56 q^{11} + 53 q^{12} + 47 q^{13} + 39 q^{14} + 
 31 q^{15} + 22 q^{16} + 15 q^{17} + 9 q^{18} + 5 q^{19} + 2 q^{20} + q^{21}$$

Why is there a $q^{21}$ term? Surely, if the "area under a multidimensional lattice path" has any meaning, the maximum area you can enclose (only one lattice path can achieve this) is $3 \times 3 \times 2 = 18$.

To make this area (i.e. volume) enclosed in higher dimensions clearer, this is an example case for ${6 \choose 2,2,2}_q$, where the area enclosed is 2.

[image]

Here, it is 4:

[image]

Is there a generating function for the area under a lattice path in $d$-dimensions (i.e. on a hypercubic lattice)? The lattice path enumeration books I see all stop at that point. They can count the paths in higher dimensions, but seem to leave out higher dimensional analogues of the $q$-analogue representation of the hypervolume underneath.

It is equivalent to partitioning an integer into $k$ parts, each less than $m$, but with I think restricted parts. For example, their are certain areas you cannot enclose with a lattice path in some cuboids, hence the polynomial generating function will have to skip certain powers of $q$.

Edit: Just to clarify, there is no current approach/text addressing the question:

*Is there a generating function for the number of $d$-dimensional lattice paths which generate an area $t$ underneath, i.e. against the faces of the encoding cuboid?*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Q-multinomial coefficient combinatorial meaning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1940045/q-multinomial-coefficient-combinatorial-meaning)

Comment: Thank you, that goes a good way to explain. For the other part, on the whole, is their a generating function for the area under a lattice path in $d$-dimensions? I'm able to formulate it as a integer partiton problem, but where the parts are restricted to the parts of another integer partition (of an integer less than or equal to the area of one of the faces of the cuboid). So one can use $\Pi_{s}1/(1-x^s)$, with $s$ the set of restricted parts e.g. $s=\{1,3,4\}$, like a change making problem.

Comment: I think you should ask that as a separate question. If you do, you should also clarify how you define the area under a path.