# Is there a $q$-analog for the product of binomial coefficients?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, algebraic-combinatorics, q-analogs

The $q$-analog of the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ may be defined as the coefficient of $x^k$ in $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(1+q^ix)$.

Classical arithmetic identities tend to have $q$-analogs. I am interested in the following identity:
$$\binom{n}{a}\binom{n}{b}=\sum_{i=0}^{\mathrm{min}(a,b)}\binom{a+b-i}{i,a-i,b-i}\binom{n}{a+b-i}$$

This can be proved by comparing the coefficient of $x^ay^b$ in both $(1+x)^n(1+y)^n$ and $(1+x+y+xy)^n$.

> **Question:** Is there a $q$-analog of this identity?

For example, we have $\binom{n}{1}^2=2\binom{n}{2}+n$, and its $q$-analog is
$$\binom{n}{1}_q^2=(q+q^2)\binom{n}{2}_q+q^{n-1}\binom{n}{1}_q$$

What replaces $\binom{a+b-i}{i,a-i,b-i}$ in general? Is there a version where the coefficients don't depend on $n$?

Comment: you should refer to q-multinomial. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1940068/909868)

Comment: @Aspen I'm aware of q-multinomials. How are they relevant here?

Comment: I thought that the coefficient of $x^k$ in $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(1+q^ix)$ was $q^{k(k-1)/2} \binom nk_q$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov there are different conventions out there. You are referring to the one where $n_q$ is symmetric around the term $q^0$, I’m referring to the one where e.g. $3_q=1+q+q^2$.

Comment: See Theorem 3.2 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.06110.pdf .  In fact, there are two different proofs given there.

Comment: @Nate This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to expand on Nate's answer (thank you!) and close the question:
The $q$-analog of the identity is:
$$\binom{n}{a}_q\binom{n}{b}_q=\sum_{i=0}^{\mathrm{min}(a,b)}q^{(a-i)(b-i)}\binom{a+b-i}{i,a-i,b-i}_q\binom{n}{a+b-i}_q$$

Comment: But if anyone does want to look at that paper I linked to, there is lots of cool stuff there...